# It's the same definition

Tags: meaning-in-context

> - Parents **should** spend as much time with
>   their children as possible
> - lt's an amazing book - you *should* read it.
> - You shouldn't drive so fast.
>
> I think that the meanings of "**should**" and "*should*" are different. To me,
> should" means "it is correct to" and "should" means "I think it is better for you to" Am I right?

> **It**'s the same definition in both examples - both used to indicate the speakers
> belief that a certain action is the correct one.

---

There are the two "should"s, so it seems to me that "they" should be used instead of "**it**".
What exactly does "**it**" refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "it" there refer to the following word "definition", and the statement claims the definition in both uses is the same.

However, even if there were several definitions, "it" could be used, because in your example it's a dummy subject, as explained here:

[Cambridge dummy subjects](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects)

A similar use:
"It's the cars that have been left in the street that are blocking traffic."

In that case, "it" refers to "cars", even though "cars" is plural.

Answer (score 1):

> There are the two "should"s, so it seems to me that "they" are used instead of "it".

The person you quoted is asserting that there is only one single definition. Therefore it is appropriate that they refer to that definition as *it* rather than *they*.